# UISearchController like Maps of Apple

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchcontroller

I'm developing an iOS app using Objective C.
I implemented UISearchController , It works fine I just wanted to be like Maps of Apple but it's not the case the buttons on the navigation bar doesn't disappear 
here is some screenshot .

Any ideas ?!

[Before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnYUA.png)

[After click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkvZk.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the delegate method of UISearchBar like this

On begin editing of UISearchBar remove the Navigation button like this

```
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
    return true
}
```

On cancel button click add the navigation button again

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    //Add the code you are using to previously set navigation with buttons and UISearchBar
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I would like to but I still don't have 15 reputation points :/